# How to draw a filled rectangle without a border using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Method 1:

```
\draw [fill=orange] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (0.2,0.2);
```

For the line above, by default, the filled orange rectangle will have a black border.

Method 2:

```
\draw [fill=orange,orange] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (0.2,0.2);
```

With this line, the border color will be changed to orange and thus the entire rectangle will have one color.

Unfortunately I have figure with intricate overlaps of rectangles. The borders, even though they are the same color as the `fill`, have finite thickness and mess up the sketch. Is there a way to get rid of the border altogether?

Comment: What about using `\fill` instead of `\draw`?

Comment: @Corentin: If you post this as an answer (maybe with an easy example) Shashank can accept it an this answer won’t be “unanswered” anymore … and it will bring reputations points for both of you.

Comment: @Corentin: I agree with Tobi as that is the answer. You could also add that one case use `\draw [draw=none, fill=orange]` option to eliminate the black border, or even `\draw [draw=orange, fill=orange]`.

Comment: @Tobi, I will turn this into an answer, I just wanted to make sure that I add correctly understood the question.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks! That works alright as well.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The border of the rectangle is drawn because you are using the `\draw` command, which, by definition, draws the specified path (here the rectangle). The fact that you are adding the option `fill=orange` just tells TikZ that in addition it should fill the path with orange. Replacing `\draw` with `\fill` will do what you are expecting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz \fill [orange] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (0.2,0.2);

\end{document}
```

As noted in the comments, another option is to use `\draw [fill=orange,draw=none]`. This amounts to telling TikZ to draw the path with an invisible color and fill it with orange, hence the result is the same. As drawing the path with an invisible color is maybe a little strange, it is perhaps more natural to use instead the general `\path [fill=orange]`. Note that `\draw` is simply a shortcut for `\path [draw]` and in a similar manner, `\fill` is a shortcut for `\path [fill]`. Similarly, you have the command `\filldraw` which is an abbreviation for `\path [fill,draw]`. In full generality, colors to use for either filling or drawing can be specified by replacing `fill` or `draw` by `fill=color` or `draw=color` in the options.

All these commands are documented in section 15 of the TikZ manual (and especially 15.3 and 15.4), with details and examples (accessible by the command `texdoc tikz` in a shell or [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)).

Comment: With the \fill command I *think* you just need to specify the colour so the fill= is unnecessary.

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary (forgot to suppress it after copy-pasting)

Comment: Another option is the general `\path [fill=orange]` … In my eyes it’s counterintuitive to use `\draw` and then don’t draw (`draw=none`) but fill.

Comment: @Tobi I agree, I will update my answer to reflect this better.

Comment: @strpeter Your reason to the edit is not correct. You are confusing with the command `\tikzpicture`. `\tikz` is as valid as the corresponding `tikzpicture` environment

Comment: @percusse: Yes, you are right I was confusing the two but I do not like this notation neither... ;)

Comment: It does not draw anything in my case :( I guess we need to specify the height?

Answer (score 8):

To avoid some confusion from the selected answer, another option is to use **path**

```
\path [fill=orange] (0.1,0.1) rectangle (0.2,0.2);
```