# How can I draw angles only with the outer line, but not with the line to the center?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following LaTeX-Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, calc, shapes,snakes} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \newcommand\XC{4}
    \newcommand\ALPHA{30}

    \newcommand\XB{{(\XC*(cos(\ALPHA)*cos(\ALPHA) - sin(\ALPHA)*sin(\ALPHA)) + \XC)*0.5}}
    \newcommand\YB{{sqrt(cos(\ALPHA)*\XC*cos(\ALPHA)*\XC - (\XC*(cos(\ALPHA)*cos(\ALPHA) - sin(\ALPHA)*sin(\ALPHA)) + \XC)*0.5*(\XC*(cos(\ALPHA)*cos(\ALPHA) - sin(\ALPHA)*sin(\ALPHA)) + \XC)*0.5)}}

    \newcommand\XBo{{(\XB)+4}}
    \newcommand\YBo{{\YB}}
    \newcommand\XBp{{\XB*0.5}}
    \newcommand\YBp{{\YB*0.5}}

    % Draw the triangle
    \draw[fill=gray!10]  (0,    0) coordinate (A) 
        -- (\XB,\YB) coordinate (C) 
        -- (\XC,  0) coordinate (B) 
        -- (0,    0);

    % Draw nodes
    \node at (A)[anchor=north] {A};
    \node at (B)[anchor=north] {B};
    \node at (C)[anchor=south] {C};

    % Draw edge text
    \node (c) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) [below] {c};
    \node (b) at ($(A)!0.5!(C)$) [above] {b};
    \node (a) at ($(B)!0.6!(C)$) [right] {a};


    % draw alpha
    \draw[fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (0:0.75cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.75cm);
    \coordinate[label=right:$\alpha$] (Alpha) at (0.25,0.15);

    % draw beta
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\XC, 0)}]
        \draw[fill=red!30] (0,0) -- (-180:0.50cm) arc (180:{180-(90-\ALPHA)}:0.5cm);
        \draw (150:0.35cm) node {$\beta$};
    \end{scope}

    % draw gamma
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\XB, \YB)}]
        \draw[fill=blue!30] (0,0) -- ({180+\ALPHA}:0.5cm) arc ({180+\ALPHA}:{180+\ALPHA+90}:0.5cm);
        \draw (-0.1, -0.05) node[below] {$\gamma$};
    \end{scope}


    % shifted alpha
    \begin{scope}[shift={(4,0)}]
        \draw[fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (0:0.5cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.5cm);
    \end{scope}

    % shifted gamma
    \begin{scope}[shift={(4, 0)},rotate=180]
        \draw[fill=blue!30] (0,0) -- ({180+\ALPHA}:0.5cm) arc ({180+\ALPHA}:{180+\ALPHA+90}:0.5cm);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[shift={(3.13,-0.5)}]
        \draw[dashed,red]  (0,    0)  -- (\XB,\YB);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[dashed, color=red] (-1, 0) -- (6, 0);
    \draw  (0,    0) coordinate (X) 
        -- (\XB,\YB) coordinate (Y) 
        -- (\XC,  0) coordinate (Z) 
        -- (0,    0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

That produces:

[image]

When you look close at the horizontal red dashed line, you can see a black line from the green angle. I would like to get rid of it without changing anything else in the image

I know, it comes from this line:

```
\draw[fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (0:0.5cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.5cm);
```

I could get rid of the line, if I changed the code to this:

```
\draw[fill=green!30] (0:0.5cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.5cm);
```

But then I get this:

[image]

The green background disappeared. How can I get green background, but not the black line?

Comment: Do you want a black line between the purple and the green areas (under the diagonal red line)?

Comment: I don't care about this line ... ah! You think about mirroring it, don't you? That's a nice work-around! But do you also know how to draw only the ending line?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you use `\draw[fill=green!30] (0:0.5cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.5cm) -- (0,0);` you'll get the green background without the horizontal line, but the black diagonal will be drawn twice (once by the green sector, once by the purple). If you want just the green background and the arc line, you'll have to use two paths: `\path[fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (0:0.5cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.5cm); \draw (0:0.5cm) arc (0:\ALPHA:.5cm);`

Comment: So, `\path` was what I was looking for. Don't you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Glad it helps. There's already quite a nice answer about filling without drawing at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82530/how-to-draw-a-filled-rectangle-without-a-border-using-tikz, so I think it's best if we just close this as a duplicate. It'll make it easier for others to find the other answer, and it's good to avoid duplication of answers.

Comment: Ok. I voted for closing this question. Thanks for your help!