# Borders of a filled TikZ object are drawn in PDF but not in DVI

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, miktex

I want to draw a triangle in Ti*k*Z that fades out and has no visible borders. As mentioned in [How to draw a filled rectangle without a border using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82530/how-to-draw-a-filled-rectangle-without-a-border-using-tikz) using `\fill` instead of `\draw` should do the job. When I compile my picture to DVI (latex.exe), it does. But when I compile it as a PDF (pdflatex.exe), which is more important for me, the outlines of the triangle are visible. The code for my triangle is (the loaded `tikzlibrary`s are needed for other things in this project):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft=true,fontsize=12pt,captions=nooneline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, fit, arrows, calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[top color=gray, bottom color=white] (-3,-3.5) -- (0,0) --
 (3,-3.5) -- cycle; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Screenshot of the object rendered as DVI. As wanted, no borders:

[image: Screenshot of the object rendered as DVI. As wanted, no borders]

Screenshot of the object rendered as PDF. Outline is visible:

[image: Screenshot of the object rendered as PDF. Outline is visible]

How can I get rid of those lines/borders also in the PDF? Any ideas, experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `\path` instead of `\fill` guarantees the absence of line strokes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft=true,fontsize=12pt,captions=nooneline]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, fit, arrows, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[top color=gray, bottom color=white] (-3,-3.5) -- (0,0) --
 (3,-3.5) -- cycle; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Had to search to find the difference in the code but works perfectly. Thank you!